# Getting error in the line " Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);" in the below code

Tags: android, audio-recording

```
package com.example.audiorecordtest;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AudioRecordTest extends Activity implements OnInfoListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private static String mFileName;
    long start_time;
    private RecordButton mRecordButton = null;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
    protected Uri newUri;
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;
    TextView time;

    private void onRecord(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startRecording();
        } else {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }
    private void startRecording() {
        try {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000);
            mRecorder.setOnInfoListener(this);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);   
            mRecorder.prepare();
            mRecorder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        time.setText("Recording...");
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        time.setText("");
        mRecorder = null;
        addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
        finish();
    }

    protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + mFileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    class RecordButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartRecording = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRecord(mStartRecording);
                if (mStartRecording) {
                    setText("Stop recording");
                } else {
                    setText("Start recording");
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
            }
        };

        public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start recording");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);

        }
    }

    public AudioRecordTest() {
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("mFileName" + mFileName);
        mFileName += "/recording-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".3gpp";
        System.out.println("mFileName after appending" + mFileName);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        if (imageReturnedIntent != null) {

            Uri audioUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            System.out.println("audioUri" + audioUri);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

        mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
        ll.addView(mRecordButton, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));
        time = new TextView(this);
        ll.addView(time, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));
        setContentView(ll);
    };

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:420)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:864)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at com.example.audiorecordtest.AudioRecordTest.addRecordingToMediaLibrary(AudioRecordTest.java:114)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at com.example.audiorecordtest.AudioRecordTest.stopRecording(AudioRecordTest.java:101)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at com.example.audiorecordtest.AudioRecordTest.onRecord(AudioRecordTest.java:49)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at com.example.audiorecordtest.AudioRecordTest.access$0(AudioRecordTest.java:45)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at com.example.audiorecordtest.AudioRecordTest$RecordButton$1.onClick(AudioRecordTest.java:124)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-26 11:01:38.750: E/AndroidRuntime(23749):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 11:06:37.210: I/Process(23749): Sending signal. PID: 23749 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Oh, wow... For starters, post your LogCat so we don't have to guess at what the error is. Also, take a moment and describe what you are doing when the error happens.

Comment: I had edited the question and posted the LogCat, Please check this. I want to record Audio and store it in ContentResolver. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you check the value of `mFileName` in `addRecordingToMediaLibrary` method...

Comment: mFileName value is "/storage/sdcard0/recording-1353911477242.3gpp" in addRecordingToMediaLibrary method and in OnCreate.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to move following code in the constructor to `onCreate()` method of the activity..

```
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("mFileName" + mFileName);
        mFileName += "/recording-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".3gpp";
        System.out.println("mFileName after appending" + mFileName);
```

Comment: It is throwing NullPointerException, but no detailed message is displayed in Exception.

Comment: mFileName value is "/storage/sdcard0/recording-1353911477242.3gpp" in addRecordingToMediaLibrary method and in OnCreate.